# Snowflake: Repeating rows based on column value

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How to repeat rows based on column value in snowflake using sql.

I tried a few methods but not working such as dual and connect by.

I have two columns: Id and Quantity.

For each ID, there are different values of Quantity.

Comment: this will some more focus, example input, do you have a counter, and thus want n rows, or do you have dates, or just want one row be letter in a string??

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

So if you have a count, you can use a generator:

```
with ten_rows as (
    select row_number() over (order by null) as rn
    from table(generator(ROWCOUNT=>10))
), data(id, count) as (
    select * from values 
    (1,2),
    (2,4)
)
SELECT   
   d.*
   ,r.rn
from data as d
join ten_rows as r
    on d.count >= r.rn
order by 1,3;
```

| ID | COUNT | RN |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 4 | 1 |
| 2 | 4 | 2 |
| 2 | 4 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 | 4 |

Answer (score 0):

Ok let's start by generating some data. We will create 10 rows, with a QTY. The QTY will be randomly chosen as 1 or 2.

[image]

Next we want to duplicate the rows with a QTY of 2 and leave the QTY =1 as they are.

Obviously you can change all parameters above to suit your needs - this solution works super fast and in my opinion way better than table generation.

Simply stack [SPLIT_TO_TABLE()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/split_to_table.html), [REPEAT()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/repeat.html) with a [LATERAL()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/join-lateral.html) join and voila.

[image]

```
WITH TEN_ROWS AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY NULL)SOME_ID,UNIFORM(1,2,RANDOM())QTY FROM TABLE(GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT=>10)))

SELECT 
   TEN_ROWS.* 
FROM 
   TEN_ROWS,LATERAL SPLIT_TO_TABLE(REPEAT('hire me $10/hour',QTY-1),'hire me $10/hour')ALTERNATIVE_APPROACH;
```